# Gson keeps removing "+" in string "ulva+"

Tags: android, gson

when parsing Gson in android

```
    String urlParameters = "data=" + gson.toJson(Object).toString();
```

***Stetho SQLite***
[Snip from sqlite on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqZ9m.png)

After sending the data to php server the "+" is removed

***PHP server***

```
    $json = $this->post('data');
    $medium_forms = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: That is because of the reason @Thomas mentions. [Even Google removes it](https://www.google.com/?q=hi+there). See? If you type in the URL `https://www.google.com/?q=hi+there` in the address bar, then `hi there` shows up in the search bar, removing the plus sign.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I need to url encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Gson in particular. The problem is that JSON may contain characters that are not safe for use in query strings: besides `+`, also `&` and `=` are troublesome, and there may be others. So you need to encode your URL parameter.

For encoding, you can use Java's [`URLEncoder` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

For decoding, it depends on your PHP code and what `$this` and `$this->post` are. Maybe the decoding is already done for you by some framework, maybe you need to call [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches:

1. create a custom calls identifying the param as String specifically, then use the class object to parse to json.
2. you can create a custom Gson parser.